# No genera el refresh_token en txt python-O365

Tags: python, o365-flow

Me encuentro utilizando la librería o365 de python y cuando genero el txt por medio de account.con.request_token(result_url) no me genera el refresh.token simplemente me genera el access_token, este es mi código

```
from O365 import Account

scopes_graph = protocols.get_scopes_for('message_send')
credential = ('client_id', 'client_secret')

account = Account(credentials=credential, scopes=scopes_graph)
account.con.get_authorization_url()
result_url = input('Paste the result url here...')
#'aqui crea el txt pero no genera el 
account.con.request_token(result_url) 
m = account.new_message() 
m.to.add('examples@example.com')
m.subject = 'Testing!'
m.body = "George Best quote: I've stopped drinking, but only while I'm asleep."
m.send()
```

necesito el "refresh_token":"...." gracias

Comment: No aqui, por favor; aqui es Inglesia.  
https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Sorry, I need generate a refresh_token but my code only work for 1 hour.

Comment: Relevant Meta Discussion: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/8239061

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only need used:

Chage this:

```
account = Account(credentials=credential, scopes=scopes_graph)
account.con.get_authorization_url()
result_url = input('Paste the result url here...')
#'aqui crea el txt pero no genera el 
account.con.request_token(result_url)
```

by this code

```
account = Account(credentials=credential, scopes=scopes_graph)
account.authenticate(scopes=['basic', 'message_all'])
```